# Split Column into 2+ Rows; Specify Delimiter & Maximum Character Length

Tags: bash, unix

I have a data file that consists of 10 columns and 30,000+ rows. I need to pre-process this data file for downstream use (and the final file format HAS to be Excel; keeping it as a plain text document is not an option unfortunately).

The problem I am running into is that several rows in Column 7 exceed Excel's character limit (32,767). How do I specify to break apart Column 7 so that it doesn't exceed the character limit, but so that it also keeps the context of the text within the Column? (Column 7 contains a bunch of sentences and I don't want to break them up).

For example/simplicity: The following paragraph is in Column "A". I want to break up this paragraph into "X" number of rows as shown so that each row in Column A doesn't exceed 100 characters while maintaining sentence structure.

- Delimiter: ". " {period followed by a space}
- Max Character Length: 100

> He told us a very exciting adventure story. We have never been to
>   Asia, nor have we visited Africa. Should we start class now, or should
>   we wait for everyone to get here. Everyone was busy, so I went to the
>   movie alone. Last Friday in three week’s time I saw a striped blue
>   worm shake hands with a legless lizard.

[image: Desired Output]

Here is what I have tried:

- **sed/gsub** : But this replaces every instance of the delimiter
- **fold** : But I don't know how to specify a delimiter other than space, and using the space as a wrap disrupts the sentence.
- **substr** : I think this may be the way to go, but right now, it is only (1) outputting the first "row" and (2) breaking apart the paragraph at the maximum character length rather than at the delimiter I want.

> ```
> cat paragraph | awk -F ". " 'BEGIN { OFS="\n\n"}; { $0=substr($0,1,100); print}'
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are interested in breaking up column A, you can use `sed`.
You try to match as much characters as possible with the max of 99, followed by a dot and a space.
Replace the last space with a newline.

```
columnA="He told us a very exciting adventure story. We have never been to Asia, nor have we visited Africa. Should we start class now, or should we wait for everyone to get here. Everyone was busy, so I went to the movie alone. Last Friday in three week’s time I saw a striped blue worm shake hands with a legless lizard."
echo "${columnA}" | sed -r 's/(.{1,99}\.) /\1\n/g'
```

Comment: Thanks! I was so close in hindsight!